# How to check whether javascript is enabled on browser on server side using c# in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

How to check whether javascript is enabled on browser on server side using c# in asp.net

I tried the following code but its not working.

```
if (Request.Browser.JavaScript)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/enabledpage.aspx", false);
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/disabledpage.aspx", false);
}
```

Comment: An idea would be to use Javascript to write to a hidden field. Check the value in this field from your server side, to see whether it has the expected value.

Comment: check this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71781/Check-Whether-JavaScript-and-Cookie-are-Enabled-us

Comment: FYI: [Request.Browser.JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.javascript(v=vs.110).aspx) just tells you whether or not the browser "supports" javascript, not whether it's enabled or not. So it will be true for every real browser, every time.